# Jenkins Build Order Dependencies SCM

Tags: git, maven, jenkins

I'm working on a Jenkins setup for a organization on GitHub that has ~20 repos, with various dependency hierarchies. When any repo is changed on GitHub, I want Jenkins to build that repo and all repos that depend on it. This is simple enough when pushing one repo with only a few children, but often we'll push changes to 3 or 4 repos at once, and many dependencies use provided scope in maven rather than being compiled, meaning if repo B is a parent to repo C, and repo B depends on repo A with provided scope, a change in A should only result in B being compiled (not C) in order to ensure A's changes didn't cause issues with B.

[I drew out an example that's analogous to our project structure, just smaller](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NnVyi.png)

(The dark blue lines represent a dependency that gets compiled in, while the light blue represents a "provided" dependency).

Basically, I want to setup a system where builds aren't being performed multiple times. For example, if I were to push changes to E and C in Git, I want them to both compile, then D to compile. B should also compile to ensure the changes to E didn't disrupt anything, but B's children need not compile (if it had more than just D). As another example, if I pushed A and C, I would want A, then B and C, then D to compile in that order, preferably without D being compiled multiple times (It seems inefficient to just set D to compile after upstream jobs B or C are complete).

Thanks!
Nick

Edit: [Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KRwqB.png) is a picture of the dependency layout of our actual repos that I'm trying to set this up for. Lower projects depend on higher projects and the light blue lines are "provided" dependencies rather than ones compiled in.

Comment: Setup each individual project to build on new code commits, then setup each parent job to build when one of its children completes a build?

Comment: @MattClark The issue is that will result in some projects being compiled 5+ times when a couple of their children/grandchildren are pushed to scm at once, or when multiple of their children depend on a same grandchild that is pushed to scm.

Comment: You are really playing with fire relying on Jenkins to Manage this. You should use proper Dependency Management techniques, versioning and an artifact repository.